# jquery qrcode won't run

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, javascript

I'm trying to get to run https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode in my Asp.net MVC project.

My View:

```
@section AddToHead
{
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/qrcode.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#qrcode').qrcode("this plugin is great");
            $('#qrcode').css('background-color', 'blue');
        })
    </script>
}

<div id="qrcode" style="width:250px; height:250px;"></div>
```

Firebug Net panel:

[image]

Generated Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/Content/css?v=1lHFDfiO53gH0Ynpd0nepOHHGQbGG8xGB5iFOphD8n01" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=K-FFpFNtIXPUlQamnX3qHX_A5r7TM2xbAgcuEmpm3O41"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/qrcode.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#qrcode').qrcode("this plugin is great");
                $('#qrcode').css('background-color', 'blue');
            })
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
         <div id="qrcode" style="width:250px; height:250px;"></div>
         </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/bundles/jquery?v=yMmPM1TxecYcoWtCWW3jYgH0fr9kiAasOfb-W5I001A1"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=XkxfR798CUJPhMhSd0B8VYgZWSNOTtLvz6047jf84wQ1"></script>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"c31129dd616f4963b12d9abdb096edeb"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:2720/bf0e4a26318449879acfee8ce1ec1d4b/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Commenting out the line `$('#qrcode').qrcode("this plugin is great");` makes the DIV background blue.

Any ideas why qrcode won't run?